# How to store very old dates in database?

Tags: mysql, datetime

It's not actually a problem I'm having, but imagine someone's building a website about the medieval times and wants to store dates, how would they go about it?

The spec for MySQLs `DATE` says it won't go below the year 1000. Which makes sense when the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. How can you store information about [the death of Kenneth II of Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/995) in 995? Of course you can store it as a string, but are there real date-type options?

Comment: In cases like this, you might consider using a different database; maybe PostgreSQL can provide the date ranges you need? ([the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) appear to imply a significantly greater date range is possible)

Comment: @Spudley: Oracle, DB2, Firebird don't have that limitation as well. So there are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - PostgreSQL being the most well-known open source DB after mySQL, but yes, there are plenty of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you *can* store dates below year 1000 in MySQL despite even [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) clarification:

```
mysql> describe test;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birth | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

-you still need to input year in YYYY format:

```
mysql> insert into test values (1, '0995-03-05');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------------+
| id   | birth      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 0995-03-05 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-and you'll be able to operate with this as a *date*:

```
mysql> select birth + interval 5 day from test;                                                                              
+------------------------+                                                                                                   
| birth + interval 5 day |                                                                                                   
+------------------------+                                                                                                   
| 0995-03-10             |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

As for safety. I've never faced a case when this will not work in MySQL 5.x (that, of cause, does not mean that it will 100% work, but at least it is reliable with certain probability)

About BC dates (below Christ). I think that is simple - in MySQL there's *no way* to store negative dates as well. I.e. you will need to store year separately as a signed integer field:

```
mysql> select '0001-05-04' - interval 1 year as above_bc, '0001-05-04' - interval 2 year as below_bc;
+------------+----------+
| above_bc   | below_bc |
+------------+----------+
| 0000-05-04 | NULL     |
+------------+----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1441 | Datetime function: datetime field overflow |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I think, in any case (below/above year 0) it's better to store date parts as integers in that case - this will not rely to undocumented feature. However, you will need to operate with those 3 fields not as the dates (so, in some sense that is not a solution to your problem)

Comment: Use of date-functions vs hackiness. Good tip!

Comment: @GerbenJacobs it is not documented, yes. But this will work in MySQL 5.x - I've never faced the case when it will not produce correct result

Comment: @Adam - what is 'BC' (sorry, did not found that in a question, not sure I know what it is)

Comment: BC is "before christ" meaning < 0

Comment: You made me laugh :) The years before the year 0 are "before [the birth of] christ", not "below christmas". The opposite (years > 0) are "AD" meaning "anno domini" which translates to "in the year of the lord".

Comment: @fancyPants well, the sense in the same (may be 'Below Christmas' sounds bad) - so MySQL can't hold that in any date type.

Comment: Haha before Christmas! Thats brilliant :)
Thanks for the edit anyway

Comment: a) it's BEFORE, not below x) Below christ is the whole christianity xD ...  ... b) idea - store dates before year 0 as positive `date`s and to decide whether it is BC or not, use another column e.g. `bc` of type  "boolean" <~=~> TINYINT(1)

Answer (score 2):

Choose a dbms that supports what you want to do. Among other free database management systems, PostgreSQL supports a timestamp range from 4713 BC to 294276 AD.

If you break up the date into separate columns for year, month, and day, you also need  more tables and constraints to guarantee that values in those columns represent actual dates. If those columns let you store the value {2013, 2, 29}, your table is broken. A dbms that supports dates in your range entirely avoids this kind of problem.

Other problems you might run into

- Incorrect date arithmetic on dates that are out of range.
- Incorrect locale-specific formatting on dates that are out of range.
- Surprising behavior from date and time functions on dates that are out of range.
- [Gregorian calendar weirdness](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html).

Gregorian calendar weirdness? In Great Britain, the day after Sep 2, 1752 is Sep 14, 1752. [PostgreSQL documents their rationale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) for ignoring that as follows.

> PostgreSQL uses Julian dates for all date/time calculations. This has
>   the useful property of correctly calculating dates from 4713 BC to far
>   into the future, using the assumption that the length of the year is
>   365.2425 days.
>
> Date conventions before the 19th century make for interesting reading,
>   but are not consistent enough to warrant coding into a date/time
>   handler.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think that currently the easiest option is to store year, month and day in separate fields with year as `smallint`.

Comment: And what if I want to date the start of the universe? :) Smallint does not seem right for describing the current universe :-)

Comment: You could possibly ask creators of mezzacotta.net how they handle dates (since their implementation can actually handle dates predating the age of universe) http://www.mezzacotta.net/archive.php?date=-9999999999999-01-01

Answer (score 0):

To quote from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

```
For the DATE and DATETIME range descriptions, “supported” means that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee.
```

So there's a good change that a wider range will work given a sufficiently configured MySQL installation.

Make sure not to use TIMESTAMP, which seems to have a non-negative range.

```
The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
```

Here is a JavaScript example how far before the UNIX epoch(1) you can get with 2^36 seconds * -1000 (to get to milliseconds for Javascript).

```
d = new Date((Math.pow(2, 36) - 1) * -1000)
Sun May 13 -208 18:27:45 GMT+0200 (Westeuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

So I would suggest to store historical dates as BIGINT relative to the epoch.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html for MxSQL 5.6.

---

(1)

```
epoch = new Date(0)
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Westeuropäische Normalzeit)
epoch.toUTCString()
"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
```